# Covariant return types in Java enums

Tags: java, generics, enums, covariant

As mentioned in another question on this site, something like this is not legal:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    FOO {
        public Integer doSomething() { return (Integer) super.doSomething(); }
    },
    BAR {
        public String doSomething() { return (String) super.doSomething(); }
    };

    public Object doSomething();
}
```

This is due to covariant return types apparently not working on enum constants (again breaking the illusion that enum constants are singleton subclasses of the enum type...)  So, how about we add a bit of generics: is this legal?

```
public enum MyEnum2 {
    FOO {
        public Class<Integer> doSomething() { return Integer.class; }
    },
    BAR {
        public Class<String> doSomething() { return String.class; }
    };

    public Class<?> doSomething();
}
```

Here, all three return `Class` objects, yet the individual constants are "more specific" than the enum type as a whole...

Comment: Um, the first code works for me... what error are you seeing?

Comment: Not legal, as in it would compile (glossing over `MyEnum`'s own `doSomething()` implementation), but not do anything useful, as an expression like `MyEnum.FOO.doSomething()` would still be considered to return `Object` and not `Integer` as people may think.

Comment: No, it doesn't compile: doSomething has no body and it's not abstract

Comment: @Aubin: Yes, sorry - I'd assumed that bit would be filled in, and it's the first part which isn't legal.

Comment: @KelvinChung: It would help if you'd make that clear...

Comment: I complete the code in my answer but I doesn't understand your long term intention? curiosity only?

Comment: Trying to figure out the shortcomings of using enums...

Comment: There is no breaking of illusion here... the behavior you encounter is exactly the same as with any other anonymous class instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fundamentally, the problem is that the compile-time type of `MyEnum.FOO` is `MyEnum`, *not* the specific generated subclass. You can see this without any covariance:

```
enum MyEnum {
    FOO {
        public void foo() {}
    };
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        MyEnum.FOO.foo(); // Error
    }
}
```

Basically, the compiler will *only* see the signatures declared in `MyEnum`.

Comment: What is the relationship with the question?

Comment: So in the case of the second enum (with the different types as type parameters and the declaration in the enum type itself being a wildcard), you'd still get a `Class<?>` and not anything specific even with a `MyEnum2.FOO.doSomething()` call?

Comment: @Aubin: It's exactly the same problem: the OP wasn't to know about the value-specific signatures, and they're not available because the compiler only sees `MyEnum.FOO` as being of type `MyEnum`.

Comment: @KelvinChung: Exactly - the compiler will only care about the signatures declared in `MyEnum`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use Covariant return types in Java enums, but we can't use that child type for the variable to which the return is assigned to unlike in normal class hierarchy.

```
public class EnumCovariance {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<capture#1-of ?> to Class<Integer>
      Class<Integer> something = MyEnum2.FOO.doSomething();
      Child child = new Child();
      Base base = child;
      // ok
      Class<Integer> something3 = child.doSomething();

      // Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<capture#2-of ?> to Class<Integer>
      Class<Integer> something2 = base.doSomething();
    }
}

abstract class Base {
   public abstract Class<?> doSomething();
}

class Child extends Base {
   @Override
   public Class<Integer> doSomething() {
      return Integer.class;
   }
}

enum MyEnum2 {
   FOO {
      public Class<Integer> doSomething() {
         return Integer.class;
      }
   },
   BAR {
      public Class<String> doSomething() {
         return String.class;
      }
   };

   public abstract Class<?> doSomething();
}
```

Comment: It does make the whole point of adding in a call super to implement a covariant return type somewhat useless, though... oh well...

Comment: @KelvinChung, what is the replacement for "MyEnum2.FOO.doSomething()"?

Comment: I meant that in the sense that it wouldn't matter whether `MyEnum2.FOO.doSomething()` returned a `Class<Integer>` or a `Class<?>` (beyond a sanity check, I suppose) - the compiler just sees the latter and pretty much ignores the former, methinks.

Comment: @KelvinChung, then what is the motivation of changing the return type in the implementation in the child class as we can always return Integer.class by keeping the return type Class<?>

Comment: My original question was motivated by the fact that, if you were to take enum constants as singleton subclasses of the enum type, that an expression like `MyEnum2.FOO` would refer specifically to an object of that subclass (which, as we learned, is not the case), and hence, we could make the return type of `MyEnum2.FOO.doSomething()` more specific than `myEnum2Instance.doSomething()`, even if it means inserting call supers to do so.

Answer (score 0):

This code works well:

```
public enum MyEnum {
   FOO {
      @Override
      public Integer doSomething() {
         return (Integer)super.doSomething();
      }
   },
   BAR {
      @Override
      public String doSomething() {
         return (String)super.doSomething();
      }
   };

   public Object doSomething() {
      System.err.println( this );
      return null;
   }

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      MyEnum toto = MyEnum.FOO;
      System.err.println( toto.doSomething() );
   }
}
```

output is:

```
FOO
null
```

this code doesn't compile, the error is `"The return type is incompatible with MyEnum2.doSomething()"`, `Cannot cast from Class<Object> to Class<Integer>` and `Cannot cast from Class<Object> to Class<String>`:

```
public enum MyEnum2 {
   FOO {
      @Override
      public Class<Integer> doSomething() {
         return (Class<Integer>)super.doSomething();
      }
   },
   BAR {
      @Override
      public Class<String> doSomething() {
         return (Class<String>)super.doSomething();
      }
   };

   public Class<Object> doSomething() {
      System.err.println( this );
      return null;
   }

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      MyEnum2 toto = MyEnum2.FOO;
      System.err.println( toto.doSomething() );
   }
}
```

Comment: A Class<String> is not considered assignable to a Class<Object>.  `MyEnum2.doSomething()` must return a `Class<?>`, as stated in the question.

Comment: Only null is compatible with type String and type Integer.

Comment: But last time I checked, you can't cast a Class<Object> to a Class<String>, which is what the compiler is barfing about in your `MyEnum2`.